# Button click i want to select the select option value as 'Equal'?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

```
<b><a href="#" onClick="clearValue()" > Clear </a> </b>
<script>
function clearValue() {
document.getElementById('{!$Component.page1:form1:input1}').value='';
document.getElementById('{!$Component.page1:form1:selectlist:selectoption}').value='Equal';
}          
</script>
```

by using this function .i am getting

```
document.getElementById('{!$Component.page1:form1:input1}').value=' ';
```

This set the my inputtextbox to null.

```
document.getElementById('{!$Component.page1:form1:selectlist:selectoption}').value='Equal';
```

this is not working with select option . can any body know how to write this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look for the **option** into your select element and then set it as **selected**, try:

If you have access to `jquery` you only have to:

```
$('#$Component.page1:form1:selectlist').val('Equal');
```

else:

```
function clearValue() {
   document.getElementById('{!$Component.page1:form1:input1}').value='';
   setOptionSelected(document.getElementById('{!$Component.page1:form1:selectlist}') ,'Equal');
}        

function setOptionSelected(mySelObj, myValue){
  for(var i=0,sL=mySelObj.length;i<sL;i++){
    if(mySelObj.options[i].text == myValue){
      mySelObj.selectedIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

document.getElementById('{!$Component.page1.form1.selectlist}').selectedIndex=0;

Where 0 is the index number. If 'Equal' is your 0th, 1st, 2nd... option, then update the index accordingly.

Comment: This will set only the select on the first option, if the first option is not Equal guess what

Comment: no it is not working

Comment: @MartinBorthiry of course that is for Teja to figure out what the index should be. Anyway, updated the answer.

Comment: yes Equal is my 0th option .still it is not working

Comment: Oh hey. You are not referencing the component correctly. Its not ':'. Rather you have to use '.'. And I hope the hierarchy of the component is correct, and you are not missing any pageblocks or sections in between. And it should just be till the select list. Updated my answer